# What does CRASH_RECOVER mean from Octoprint?

Tags: prusa-i3, octoprint

When watching the Raspberry PI daemon.log while running OctoPrint, I see contents like the following, which occasionally includes **enqueing "CRASH_RECOVER"** (but I do not see "CRASH_DETECTED"). This is usually preceded by "INFO - Got a resend request from the printer"

But what is it telling me when it logs **enqueing "CRASH_RECOVER"** ?

```
Sep 16 17:22:23 octoprint octoprint[413]: | Recv: T:215.3 /215.0 B:59.8 /60.0 T0:215.3 /215.0 @:65 B@:69 P:0.0 A:42.5
Sep 16 17:22:23 octoprint octoprint[413]: | Recv:   0 step= 1 mscnt=  30
Sep 16 17:22:23 octoprint octoprint[413]: | Recv: tmc2130_goto_step 1 1 2 1000
Sep 16 17:22:23 octoprint octoprint[413]: | Recv: tmc2130_home_exit tmc2130_sg_homing_axes_mask=0x02
Sep 16 17:22:23 octoprint octoprint[413]: | Recv: echo:enqueing "CRASH_RECOVER"
Sep 16 17:22:23 octoprint octoprint[413]: | Recv: T:216.4 /215.0 B:59.8 /60.0 T0:216.4 /215.0 @:49 B@:49 P:0.0 A:42.6
Sep 16 17:22:23 octoprint octoprint[413]: | Recv: echo:busy: processing
Sep 16 17:22:23 octoprint octoprint[413]: | Recv: Resend: 67875
```